# How to print google-annotated-chart by clicking on print button, just like normal print as save it as a pdf programatically?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json

How to print Google annotated chart by clicking on print button in a web page?

In my code, I used `window.print()` method, but when I print the page, chart disappears from the webpage and rest of the content is printing.

Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    <html>    <head>
       <title>Google Chart with jsp Mysql Json</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><!--
css for datepicker -->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script><!--   
Javascript for datepicker -->
       <script type="text/javascript">
           google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); $(document).ready(function(){   
showGoogleChart('2013-12-01','2013-12-31');
//============================= Onpage load calling chart function
$(    "#from" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true,
dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',    numberOfMonths: 3, onClose: function(
selectedDate ) { $( "#to"    ).datepicker( "option", "minDate",
selectedDate ); } }); $( "#to"    ).datepicker({
dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd', changeMonth: true,    numberOfMonths: 3,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) { $( "#from"    ).datepicker(
"option", "maxDate", selectedDate ); } }); });   
//==================== OnChange date call google chart   
================== function getChartdate(){ alert("hi"); var startdate = $('#from').val(); var enddate = $('#to').val();   
showGoogleChart(startdate,enddate);   //===========On button click  
calling chart function========= }
       function showGoogleChart(startdate,enddate){    
           var queryObject="";
           var queryObjectLen="";
           var postdata = {"startDate":startdate,"endDate":enddate};
           $.ajax({
               type : 'POST',
               url : 'testPages.jsp',
               data:postdata,
               dataType:'json',
               success : function(data) {
                   queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
                   queryObjectLen = queryObject.empdetails.length;

                   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(queryObject,queryObjectLen));
               },
                   error : function(xhr, type) {
                   alert('server error occoured')
               }
           });
       }


           function drawChart(queryObject,queryObjectLen) {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
               data.addColumn('string', 'date');
               data.addColumn('number', 'temp');
               for(var i=0;i<queryObjectLen;i++)
               {
                   var name = queryObject.empdetails[i].date;
                   var empid = queryObject.empdetails[i].temp;
                   data.addRows([
                       [name,parseInt(empid)]
                   ]);
               }
               var options = {
                   title: 'Employee Information',
               };   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data,options);  }
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
            <div style="margin: 50px;">
               <label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text"
id="to" name="to"> <input type="button" id="changeChart"   
onclick="getChartdate();" value="Change Chart"/>
           </div>
             <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: You'll need to add more info. (code sample etc.) if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: My main concern is that i have a webpage in which i am getting google annotated chart from google side. in that same page i had provided to the user a print button option , but when i am clicking onthat button , print window pop ups but google chart doesn't appear , rest of the page is as it is and come into print , but i want the complete webpage to be print along with the chart. I am using window.print() method , and i think chart is in svg or flash format.  please help  , i wanted to deliver it to my client. and thanks for your quick response Stein G Strindhaug

Comment: Do you have a public testserver with this code? Or could you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: The chart on the Google Charts developer page does print for me using Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chart/ Does that one work for you?

Comment: yes that is working for me, what i will do is i will show you the code which will produce the graph on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

The method `window print()` will simply open the print dialog. How the page is formatted for print depends on how the browser formats webpages and the print stylesheet if present.

Assuming the chart is some kind of image (or canvas), it might be that the browser choses to strip images when printing. Especially if the image is added using css `background-image: url(...)` because it assumes a background image (like background-color) is just for decoration and would waste ink if printed.

A plain `img` tag should print though in most cases unless some css is removing it for print...

Comment: My main concern is that i have a webpage in which i am getting google annotated chart from google side. in that same page i had provided to the user a print button option , but when i am clicking onthat button , print window pop ups but google chart doesn't appear , rest of the page is as it is and come into print , but i want the complete webpage to be print along with the chart. I am using window.print() method , and i think chart is in svg or flash format. please help , i wanted to deliver it to my client. and thanks for your quick response Stein G Strindhaug